# Docker sharing files between flask app and rq worker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am currently running a docker container containing a flask app with nginx based on this reposirtor: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

I have also created an image with an rq worker to which my app is connected. The usage scenario is that I have a webpage through which I upload a file which is received and saved by my flask `uploadFile`. Before using docker I just had to pass the path to the file to my RQ worker to process. However, now the worker does not have access to the same directories thus, it is not finding the file.

What is the best way to share files between 2 containers in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to share files between two docker containers the best approach is to create volume mounts. This volume will be managed by docker and be still available even if the containers are not using it. Please refer the documentation for more details.

[Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)

Consider the following example where two containers share a named volume.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app1:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
        - mydata: location_in_container

  app2:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
        - mydata: location_in_container


volumes:
  mydata:
```